# Can you keystone an image in pure css?

Tags: css, graphics

I'm putting together a webpage which has a large image on the left side, and I'd like to have it seem tilted away from the viewer. I know that the transform function isn't quite capable of it. Is there a way to keystone an image using only CSS? If not, is there some extension to the language that I could safely (i.e. in a cross-browser manner) use to create this effect programmatically? For reference, keystoning as a visual effect looks like this: [Keystone diagram](http://www.projectors-av.co.uk/pics/keystone_lens_shift/keystone.gif). It is *not* the same thing as a skew, and it is an image distortion, rather than a crop.

Comment: you can achieve this with CSS masking..

Comment: Not quite, keystoning is a distortion. I can't afford to clip off the top and bottom of my picture.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in just CSS (but I could be wrong) Just curious though, why does it need to be done with CSS instead of editing the native image? It seems like it would be much easier to just Photoshop the image. Since you're loading the image either way, there wouldn't be any performance gains from using CSS

Comment: I'm curious about your "keystone". Is this what you're talking about?http://jsfiddle.net/FqgbP/

Comment: @Dryden Long, I just hoped to be able to swap out the image occasionally and make it a one-time change in the code.

Comment: @TimSPQR, no? It doesn't seem to have done anything to the image... I'm running the current version of Chrome if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: @EmmettR. Makes Sense... Here is the fiddle Tim made, just for Chrome and facing the direction you described (I think): http://jsfiddle.net/Cwrs7/

Comment: Oh, didn't think about it...I'm an IE nerd. On IE it is rotated on an vertical axis counter-clockwise. @Dryden Long - on IE the image is unchanged (square) - I'm not tutored at all on browser differences.

Comment: @TimSPQR The link I posted had the `webkit` prefix on the `transform` property... Some browsers require a vendor specific prefix for some CSS properties. Here is the breakdown for [transofrm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility). Here's a new fiddle that should work in all browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/CY5pM/

Comment: @Dryden Long - Oh superb! Thanks very much!

Comment: Wonderful! Very helpful. Thank you both very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for axial rotations with perspective. Suppose that you have two nested divs, #back and #fore. The following CSS will achieve the effect. See also http://jsfiddle.net/4j8pn/6/. (In general, by the way, -webkit-transform is capable of any 3D transformation.)

```css
#back {
  margin:25px;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:#555;
  /* pull the viewer back; without this the div will look flat */
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
}

#fore {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:#999;
  /* set origin to upper left (default is center) to get desired look */
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0 0;
  /* rotateY tilts the div like a door, rotateX tilts it like an awning */
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(35deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="back">
  <div id="fore">
    <img src="image_to_tilt.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```